# Javascript onKeyUp

Tags: javascript

so I'm working on a mock version of google censorship for history class. I'm trying to get the search to work upon pressing enter, but so far all I get is a search upon the first letter I enter. Any suggestions?

HTML code:

```
<form id="searchBox">
    <input type="text" id = "search" name="search" size="85" onKeyUp="searchCensor()"/><br />        
</form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function searchCensor() 
{
    var keyTerms = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if(keyTerms == "censorship")
        window.location = "http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/history/censor.php";
    else if(window.event.keyCode == 13)
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+keyTerms;
    else 
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+keyTerms;
}
```

Comment: Post your code *here*, that way, once your problem's fixed, the question will still have merit to future visitors. Post [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to play with, and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your logic:

> If the search field has the value "censorship", go straight to this page
>
> Else, if the key hit was [Enter], search on google the value of the search field
>
> Else, in any other case, search on google the value of the search field

Now, say, you're hitting "e" in your search field. What happens?

> First check: it's not "censorship", skip
>
> Second check: the hit key is not [Enter], skip
>
> Third check: Alright, none of the checks before passed, I'm doing this.

So you end up searching on Google for the letter "e".

Do you see how this is wrong?

That said, take off the `else` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which key is being pressed ... you are running your function each time ANY key is being pressed right now. Inside your searchCensor() function you will want to have a check like this: `if (event.keyCode == 13) {`